# How do I debug a dynamically loaded resource in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I hit

Ctrl Shift J to bring up the Debugger.

I then went to the source tab.

The source tab states that you should hit Ctrl O to open a file.  However, the only source it pulls up is the index.htm page and one statically loaded file.

I want to step through a dynamically loaded file.

That is a file that I called via ajax and then appended to the DOM.

Is there a way to do this in Chrome?

Comment: This https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging is supposed to do what you want, but it's not working for me in an injected HTML file with JS in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + C in chrome.

Go To Source tab in the Chrome inspector that comes up, put a breakpoint on any file and line that you want to debug.

Reload the page and debug

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of file, you should be able to use this developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Note that whilst the documentation says the source map should be of the format `//#`, this didn't work for me for an injected HTML file with JS in it, but when I changed it to `//@`, then it worked and I could see the file listed in inspector (under the "domain" '(no domain)').